# Automate the process of adding email addresses to Google Docs permissions list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, automation, permissions, google-drive-api

I'm trying to set up a system where clients purchase a video in WooCommerce and then receive an email with a link to the video hosted on Google Drive. This part is done and works.

What I need to do next is to make sure that only buyers can view the video, to minimize "link trafficking", as there is an online community, Facebook groups and so on of people interested in this type of material and would likely share the link once they purchase it. I'm aware there is no way to secure it completely, just as Netflix is unable to crack down on account sharing.

So in order to restrict access to only buyers, I want to add specific permissions to the file in Google Drive, based on the email that the customer provides when checking out of the online store.

I've gone with Google Drive because it's cheaper than buying the required tons of Gigs on our web hosting to host the videos.

**My question is:**

How can I automate the process of adding email addresses to the permissions section of that Google Drive file?

**The ideal solution would be:**

- User buys video and receives link to video
- User's email (as provided at checkout) is added to the permissions list (Sharing Options) in Google Drive
- Non-users cannot view the video

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads or https://www.google.com/search?q=google+drive+api+download+file+php&oq=google+drive+api+download+file

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add new permissions to a file, you can make use of Drive API's `Permissions: create` method.

This can be done by using the below request:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileId/permissions
```

Where `fileId` is the id of the video you want to be shared.

And you should also add the below request body

```
{
  "kind": "drive#permission",
  "type": "user",
  "emailAddress": "EMAIL_ADDRESS",
  "role": "writer"
}
```

#### Note

Please bear in mind that the above body can be customized depending on your needs.

#### Suggestion

Since you want to add the permissions based on a purchase, you can set up in place an Apps Script script which does the above mentioned and you can trigger its execution by using a time-based trigger.

Apps Script is a powerful development platform which can be used to build … web apps and automate tasks. What makes it special is the fact that it is easy to use and to create applications that integrate with G Suite. Since you want to use the Drive API you have two options of achieving this: using the integrated `DriveApp` service or making use of the advanced `Drive` service. Both of them would allow you to achive the same request as above and using a trigger.

#### Reference

I suggest you take a look at the links below since they might be of help to you:

- [Permissions:create Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create?);
- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script);
- [DriveApp Class Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app);
- [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive);
- [Apps Script Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers).